# Use asynctask to call a function in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As below code shows I have a function named `record()` I want to call this function with asynctask but I do not know how to work with asynctask, record function takes long to do some tasks so I need to use asynktsak.

```
public class Record extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    String name;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    record();

}

public void record() {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Comment: First do some R&D if any confusion then you can ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
 public class Record extends Activity {

        MediaPlayer mp;
        String name;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.record);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        new Task1().execute();  

    }


class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
            super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
            {
               //Record method 
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: causes error for Task1.execute(); `cannot make static refrence to non-static`

Comment: now try above code first i forget to add new before Task1().execute().

Comment: @amirsecretery mine pleasure.

Comment: @amirsecretery recently i have same question thats why your question good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make `AsyncTask` Class and write code there and call your `AsyncTask` Class by `new AsyncTaskClass().execute();`

Comment: I got this error while attemptong to run record Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for your reference.

public void record() {

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void() {

@Override
            protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
}
Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            }


}.execute();
  }
```

Comment: and what should I write in doInBackground and onPostExecute?

Comment: for that read this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, understadn proper what exactly asynctask doing and then impmenent. 

Please accept and upvote my answer, so others can found it useful.

Comment: This a wrong syntax @pratt
It is not possible to make this type of AsyncTask