# Android program logic flow of using callbacks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android App, in which I need to make a lot of http queries. Since Android has a constrain to prevent program making http request on UI thread, I have to use a lot of Async methods to get response from the server. I am not a guru of using callbacks, there's a code design problem I am facing now:

Basically, I have a activity to display. I want the app to make a HttpRequest to server when the activity is created, so I can prepare the content of the activity based on the query response.

Since I am using the Google Volley library to make http requests, my code design is:

```
// in the Activity
OnCreate(Bundle b){

String response = RequestManager.makeRequest(args);

// other works based on the response in this activity.
}



// RequestManager Class
public static String makeRequest(args){

String url = getUrl();

// response callback
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            // Don't know what to do here
        }   
    };

// error callback
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            // deal with errors
        }
    };

BuildRequestAndPushToQueue(url, responseListener, errorListener);

// No way to return the response!
}
```

I know my design is totally incorrect, because `String response = RequestManager.makeRequest(args);` is intent to wait for a blocking call, but the call is actually async. 

**My ultimate goal is to let the response String returned to some code in the activity**, so it can use the activity context to do the rest works (like access to a imageview, etc). But I am not sure how to design the code flow to make this happen.

Comment: check this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247254/use-asynctask-to-call-a-function-in-android/19247823#19247823

Comment: @Allan, good idea to use Volley. It does make life easier. Just run your UI updates in `onResponse`, use an interface or even a broadcast to make call-backs.